# JavaScript/PHP/MySQL not inserting into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, insert

On my website, I have a JavaScript function that saves data into a MySQL database. It works by sending the data to a PHP file, which processes it, and then inserts it into the database.

I was fiddling around with it, and it no longer inserts new information into the database. It still works fine when updating existing information in the database, but when I try to add new information in, nothing happens, The information is not there, and no error is displayed.

Here is my PHP code: (Obviously, I have already connected and selected the database)

```
$query = mysql_query( "insert into parts values( 0, " . mysql_escape_string( $objectID ) . ", " . $objectStackID . ", " . $objectCardID . ", '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['name'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['partorder'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['top'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['left'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['width'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['height'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['stype'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['value'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['script'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['visible'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['disabled'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['style'] ) . "', '" .
    mysql_escape_string( $objectProperties['family'] ) . "' )" );

if( ! $query )
{
    logThis('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    logThis("inputted sucessfully - here come the objectprops");
    logThis("Button properties:");
    logThis("Name: " . $objectProperties['name']);
    logThis("Part order: " . $objectProperties['partorder']);
    logThis("Top: " . $objectProperties['top']);
    logThis("left: " . $objectProperties['left']);
    logThis("width: " . $objectProperties['width']);
    logThis("height: " . $objectProperties['height']);
    logThis("stype: " . $objectProperties['stype']);
    logThis("value: " . $objectProperties['value']);
    logThis("script: " . $objectProperties['script']);
    logThis("visible: " . $objectProperties['visible']);
    logThis("disabled: " . $objectProperties['disabled']);
    logThis("style: " . $objectProperties['style']);
    logThis("family: " . $objectProperties['family']);
}
```

The logThis function writes the contents to a txt file, which is useful for debuging. In the txt file, I receive the message "inputted successfully - here come the objectprops" followed by the values (that should have been) inserted into the database. However, when I look at the database, nothing has been added.

This code did work fine at one point, however, I have been editing it on and off for about 6 months now, only testing to see if it will update information, not create now info (really stupid!), so I have no idea when it was last working, and what I changed to make it stop.

I think that my JavaScript is OK, as PHP receives the correct values (as can be seen from the log), but just does not actually insert them into the database.

Can anyone see what I have done wrong? Nay help at all would be greatly appreciated. I have been staring at this code for a long time now!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT - [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30020418/javascript_code.txt) is the javascript code, basically it cycls through an array, getting properties of buttons and then sends them to the save php file. Seems to work OK, but there might be a hidden error causing the issue

Comment: Can you try doing `die()` with the query just echoed and seeing what it looks like? So replace `mysql_query` with `die`. Additionally you should be using mysqli as mysql_* is depreciated and insecure.

Comment: @Jono20201 Will this work if I never actually see the contents of the page? It is AJAX, so will I ever see the message? This is why I created the logThis function. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use your browsers web inspector to see what is returned by ajax messages without logging output manually. In Chrome you can open this with ctl+shift+i (windows) however you can usually find it in your browsers options/tools menu.

Comment: *"This code did work fine at one point, however, I have been editing it on and off for about 6 months now"* --- Always work with copies, so you can revert to a working one when something like this happens. Date them like I do.